# Passing C# Exception message to VB Application

Tags: c#, com, exception, vb6

I have C# component which is COMVisible.
I registered it using regasm.

This component is being used in an another VB application.
This VB application is handling error like this:

```
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler
...some code here..

MyErrorHandler
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise Err.Number, , "Failure In COM Object" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Err.Description
End If
```

I would like to pass the value of C# Exception Message to Err.Description.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Its just a `String` what have you tried?

Comment: I just want to pass the Message value caught in Exception object of C# application.

Comment: Are you raising a COMException in C#?

Comment: The exception's message is already passed as the error description. The error number however will be up in the millions (by default)

Comment: @JamesKyburz no I am not using COMException. The .NET component is set to throw whatever exception happened in its code base.

Comment: @Deanna, For instance, Consider the FileNotFound exception happening in .NET dll, the Exception message clearly shows the file name which is missing. When this exception is passed into VB Hosting application what I get is "Automation Error: System Can not find the specified file". Okay, It is fair to some degree, but It does not tell which fill is missing. If the Exception message is already passed to error description then I should be able to see the missing file name?!

Comment: @vijay Oh, I'd always seen the exact same message on my exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you passing the error message from the COM object. Are you able to retrieve the error message from your COM object? If yes, you simply add it to `Err.Raise` in place of `Err.Description`. If you can't retrieve, thats a totally different fish. Please elaborate.

```
Err.Raise Err.Number, , "Failure In COM Object" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & objYourComObject.Description
```

Comment: That's what the OP is trying to do, get the full message of the exception raised by the C# object. This (or some representation of it) will be saved in the `Err` object. Using a seperate property just makes a mess IMO :)